# SATA Drive Not Detected When Booted from External

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, ssd

I used Carbon Copy Cloner to make a bootable backup on an external USB 3.0 HDD and installed an SSD in my MacBook Pro. The SSD has OSX on it and I can boot to it fine.

When I boot to the HDD to try to copy over to the SSD, OSX does not detect the SSD. There is only the external drive listed in disk utility and System Information says that no ATA drive is connected.

Comment: The SSD has OSX 10.8 and the backup has 10.8.3 I'm going to try updating the SSD and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Now the drive is detected, but it is readonly, so I cannot partition it.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution. I first upgraded to the latest version of OSX on the new drive. Then I booted to the SSD and partitioned the drive. After doing this OSX allowed my to totally wipe and re-partition the SSD when booted up on the external drive.